# SQL Server trigger issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sugarcrm

I did try to search for my problem before but I even don't know how to sum it up in one sentence. So I am sure that the question isn't that hard. I'll try to explain

I'm working on a open source CRM (SugarCRM), and when I create a new "Role" in the CRM, there is two Insert query done on two different table : role and role_custom

My trigger is on role_custom and runs quite fine. But the insert query is firstly done on role_custom and then on role. (I've noticed that with a SQL Server Profiler).

The problem is that I need some of the info which are inserted after my trigger runs. How can I manage this in order to wait that the insert query which is done on role table is done before the trigger launches ?

And how is called that problem ? (For future myselfish researches)

(Sorry about my english btw. Really)

Here I put my trigger, maybe it could help to find a way...

```
ALTER TRIGGER 
[dbo].[trg_insert_update_tdr_type_cstm_copy_of_info]
ON [sugarCRM].[dbo].[tdr_type_cstm]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE 
        [sugarCRM].[dbo].accounts_cstm
    SET 
        date_of_c = (SELECT date_autorisation_of_c 
                     FROM inserted),
        numero_of_s_c = (SELECT autorisation_of_c 
                         FROM inserted)
    WHERE 
        accounts_cstm.id_c = (SELECT account_id 
                              FROM [SugarCRMReporting].dbo.uv_account_contact 
                              WHERE role_id = (SELECT id_c 
                                               FROM inserted)
                             )
GO
```

That [SugarCRMReporting].dbo.uv_account_contact is actually reading inside role table (that's why my trigger dont works on insert I think...)

Thanks for watching

Comment: I can't quite work out what you are asking? Sorry

Comment: Are you needing information, which is generated during the first trigger in your second trigger?

Comment: I just have one trigger.
Just to make it clear. The problem is that my trigger needs information on a table which is updated after the trigger runs.

Comment: Why not just move the trigger to the `role` table instead?  Then all of your data will be there.

Comment: It could be great ! Could you tell me how I can access the data from role_custom instead in the trigger ? When I try to write the full "path" I get the "Multi-part identifier ********** could not be bound"

Comment: Your trigger is broken. `inserted` can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows. As soon as multiple rows come along, `= (SELECT autorisation_of_c FROM inserted)` is going to generate an error along the lines that a subquery returned more than one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we put your code like this:

```
UPDATE 
    account
SET 
    account.date_of_c = inserted.date_autorisation_of_c,
    account.numero_of_s_c = inserted.autorisation_of_c
FROM [sugarCRM].[dbo].accounts_cstm AS account 
JOIN [SugarCRMReporting].dbo.uv_account_contact AS ac ON account.accounts_cstm = ac.account_id
JOIN inserted ON ac.role_id = inserted.id_c
```

Now, whitin role, we change INSERTED for role_custom and add a new filter with the inserted/updated role:

```
UPDATE 
    account
SET 
    account.date_of_c = rc.date_autorisation_of_c,
    account.numero_of_s_c = rc.autorisation_of_c
FROM [sugarCRM].[dbo].accounts_cstm AS account 
JOIN [SugarCRMReporting].dbo.uv_account_contact AS ac ON account.accounts_cstm = ac.account_id
JOIN inserted ON inserted.role_id = ac.role_id
JOIN role_custom AS rc ON ac.role_id = rc.id_c
```